# How can I render a Django Formset with some data for update process?

Tags: django, formset

I am using Dajngo formset with inlineformset_factory
What I need it when the user click in the update like It should render formset with the value.
This is the code I did but nothing works:
This is how I create a formset

```
OrderItemFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Order, OrderItem, fields='__all__', extra=1, can_delete=False)
```

And here how I tried to render the formset with the `queryset=my_query_set`.

```
if 'id' in kwargs.keys():
            order = Order.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('id'))
            order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=kwargs.get('id'))
        else:
            order = None
            order_items = None
        order_form = OrderForm(instance=order)
        print(order_items)
        order_item_form = OrderItemFormset(queryset=order_items)
```

When I click in the update link Django render the Parent form with the data I need, but this does not work with formset it just give me one row with empty data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying to solve my problem I found that I use `queryset`, and I think I should use `instance` instead.
And the other thing is that the instance was from `OrderItem` model and instead it should be from the `Order` model so the code should look like this.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'id' in kwargs.keys():
            order = Order.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('id'))
        else:
            order = None
        order_form = OrderForm(instance=order)
        order_item_form = OrderItemFormset(instance=order)
        orders = Order.objects.all()
        context = {'order_form': order_form,
                   'order_item_form': order_item_form, 'orders': orders}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```